# Is possible to pass C++11 param to Buildroot config?

Tags: c++, c++11, buildroot, build-system

I want to build boost and other packages in buildroot with -std=c++11?
Is it possible to pass it globally, instead by patching program .mk files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way to pass it globally, and for a good reason: some packages may not build with C++11, e.g. because they use new reserved words.

If you really want to risk it, however, you have three options:

- Add `-std=c++11` to `BR2_TARGET_OPTIMIZATION` (in the Toolchain menu). This will be included in the toolchain wrapper and therefore be used for each compile. Note that for C programs, this will give you "command line option ‘-std=c++11’ is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C" warnings. So packages that to -Werror will break.
- Modify package/Makefile.in and add `-std=c++11` to `TARGET_CXXFLAGS`. In this case, it's only passed to C++ compiles. However, `TARGET_CXXFLAGS` is just passed to the package build system and not all build systems honor it.
- Modify `toolchain/toolchain-wrapper.c` to add this option when g++ is called. This doesn't have the disadvantages of the other two, but is more work to implement.